# Передать в контроллер массив неопределенной длинны через post запрос

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, controller

Мне нужно передать в контроллер массив неопределенной длины через post запрос. Попытался сделать таким образом - localhost:8080/rest/api/servicename?id=41&id=12

```
String putTicket1Request(@QueryParam("id") ArrayList<String> id,
                             @RequestBody String epMO,
                             HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest);
```

в id ничего не приходит. body уже занят xml. не охота расширять его для этих целей. Можно ли передать через QueryParam?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь передать id в качестве названия коллекции ArrayList. Массив это не коллекция. Если хотите передать параметр id в качестве размера массива, тогда примите этот id как int или long на контроллере, а далее уже в теле контроллера создавайте нужный массив, что-то вроде String[] array = new String[id]

Comment: и как мне потом считать переменное количество пришедших параметров?

Comment: Создавайте массив на клиенте, добавляйте сразу все параметры и передавайте его на сервер. Ваш пример с передачей нескольких параметров id в запросе уже порождает неоднозначность, т.к. параметры имеют одинаковое название. Тем более, как будет выглядеть url если id будет сто штук например?

Comment: передавать длинную строку с разделителем "12_23_34_45_56"? Можно и так в принципе

Comment: Это так называемый "костыль". Сделать можно как душе угодно. Тут можно так же задать вопрос, для чего Вам post запрос, если Вы не передаете ничего кроме парвметров в url?

Comment: в теле я передаю xml потому и post. можно конечно передавать json с двумя полями - одно xml а другой массив. Чтобы не плодить костылей я и создал эту тему, может кто что дельное подскажет.